# What packages are installed by `sudo apt-get install r-base`?

Tags: apt, r

I have add the following link to my repository list

```
deb http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

1. When running `sudo apt-get install r-base`, what packages in
   http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/?C=M;O=D are
   installed? Is it this one:

   ```
   r-base_3.1.3-1trusty_all.deb                  09-Mar-2015 17:46   37K
   ```

   But it is too small.
2. When running `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`, what packages  are
   installed?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say it's too small, and why can't you run `apt-cache depends r-base` and find for yourself?

Comment: The link shows r-base_3.1.3-1trusty_all.deb  is only 37K

Comment: You said that already. What size do you expect it to be, and why?

Comment: > 10MB, according to my previously installed files belonging to R.

Comment: Packages change. What may have been in one package may now be shifted to another package or to a new package altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r-base` is a metapackage.

```
apt-cache show r-base
```

> ... 
>   This package is a metapackage which eases the transition from the 
>   pre-1.5.0 package setup with its larger r-base package. Once
>   installed, it  can be safely removed and apt-get will automatically
>   upgrade its components  during future upgrades.  Providing this
>   package gives a way to users to  then only install `r-base-core` if they
>   so desire.

The base R installation files are in package `r-base-core`:

```
apt-cache show r-base-core
```

> ... 
>   This package provides the core GNU R system from which only the
>   optional  documentation packages `r-base-html`, `r-doc-html`, `r-doc-pdf`
>   and `r-doc-info`  have been split off to somewhat reduce the size of
>   this package.

You can view the dependencies of the R packages on their [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) pages:

- [r-base](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/r-base)
- [r-base-core](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/r-base-core)
- [r-base-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/r-base-dev)

Comment: Sorry about the mistake I introduced in my edit. (r-base-core is of course not a metapackage.) I'm glad you caught it.